# VBA Excel - Merge cells in column B based on column A merge

Tags: vba, excel, mergesort

I have a routine that merges sequential cells in column A. I need to merge the cells in column B that are sequentially matching, but NOT merge across the row boundaries of the merged column A cells. My merge for column A is working as expected.

However, if the values in column B have sequential values that begin next to merged A cell and continue into the next cell, they merge across the boundary. How do I base my merger of sequentially matching B cells on the already merged A cells?

Here's how my code currently merges the row boundaries of column A's merged cells:

[image: Example]

Here's how I intend for it to look:

[image: Example of Successful Merge]

My current code:

```
Sub MergeV()
    ' Merge Administration and Category where sequentional matching rows exist

    ' Turn off screen updating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long

    For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngMerge = Current.Range("A2:B" & lrow)

MergeAgain:
        For Each cell In rngMerge
            If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False Then
                Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
                GoTo MergeAgain
            End If
        Next

    Next Current

    ' Turn screen updating back on
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Any guidance on accomplishing this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: for starters you should turn both `ScreenUpdating` and `DisplayAlerts` back "on" by setting them back to `True` following `Application.Calculation`

Comment: Do a check using *? cell.Offset(-1,0).MergeArea.Address* to ensure that the last row in the range of the Column A cells is <= the current cell's row.  Add that to your If statement.

Comment: @Marcucciboy2 Strictly speaking, Excel resets `ScreenUpdating` to True automatically, but as to me I prefer to state it explicitly.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Cyril. I added the following to my If statement, but it did not change the outcome.       _If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False And cell.Row <= cell.Offset(-1, -0).MergeArea.Address Then_

Comment: @JohnMiller the check involves the full "? cell.offset(-1,0).mergearea.address" which should provide a range back.  you would need to determine the final row of that range, which is probably best kept as a variable (k), then your if statement includes cell.row <= k

Comment: @Cyril - So how do I test the range of merged cells in A while doing the merge of B? I get that I can set k = final row of merged cell in A. But, I'm not sure how to reference that as I do the merge in B column.

Comment: I am able to set a variable to the final row of the merge area in column A using _'If cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeCells Then     k=cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Count    l=cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Row    m=l+k-1'_  I still can't get this to work because my if statement _('If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False And cell.Row <= m Then')_ fails because the _cell.Row_ does not increment when moving to the next cell. ?cell.Row = 2 before and after the merge. Any suggestions for how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was difficult to solve. Once column A is merged, when merging sequentially matching cells in column B, I can check to see if the neighboring cell in column A is merged *cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeCell*. I can also get the first merged row *j = cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Row* and calculate the last merged row by taking the count of merged rows *k = cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Count* and setting *lastmergerow = j + k -1* (subtract 1 to get the end of the MergeArea).

However, the key is to set and update variables while looping through the range. In the code below, I updated the start and end rows for the range to keep from merging past the MergeArea from the A column. This allowed me to merge sequentially matching values in column B while keeping within the MergeArea from column A.

Avoid working with merged cells whenever possible!!! But, in the rare occasion that someone needs to do this, I hope the following code helps.

My FinalCode:

```
    Sub MergeB()
    ' Merge Category (Column B) where sequentially matching rows exist while staying within the range of merged cells in Administration (Column A)
    ' Turn off screen updating
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Dim Current As Worksheet
    Dim lrow As Long
    Dim k As Long
    Dim j As Long
    Dim bRow As Long
    Dim endRow As Long
        For Each Current In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        bRow = 2
        lrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
        endRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row
    MergeAgain:
        Set rngMerge = Current.Range("B" & bRow & ":B" & lrow)
                    For Each cell In rngMerge
                    If cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeCells Then
                        k = cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Count
                        j = cell.Offset(0, -1).MergeArea.Row
                        lastmergerow = j + k - 1
                        m = k - 1
                    End If
                    Dim i As Integer
                        For i = 1 To m
                            If cell.Value = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value And IsEmpty(cell) = False And bRow < lastmergerow Then
                                Range(cell, cell.Offset(1, 0)).Merge
                                bRow = bRow + 1
                            Else
                                bRow = bRow + 1
                                lrow = lastmergerow
                                If bRow > endRow Then
                                    GoTo NextSheet
                                End If
                                If bRow > lrow Then
                                    lrow = endRow
                                End If
                                GoTo MergeAgain
                            End If
                        Next i
                                bRow = lastmergerow + 1
                                lrow = endRow
                                GoTo MergeAgain
                    Next
    NextSheet:
                Next Current
    ' Turn screen updating back on
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Call AutoFit
    End Sub
```